# Shaping input for Many-To-One LSTM Keras

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm using an LSTM model in a ddpg reinforcement algorithm. My input is 10-time steps with each step having 100 features. The problem I'm facing is that when attempting to pass one example of 10-time steps, with 100 features, the model treats it as 10 different examples and outputs a list of 10 predicts, vs just one prediction for the 10 time-step windows.

Here is my code for the model:

```
with self.strategy.scope():

            init = tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform() 
            last_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-0.003, maxval=0.003)
            model = keras.Sequential()

            model.add(LSTM(500, input_shape=(10, 100), activation='relu', return_sequences=True, name="digits", kernel_initializer=init))
            model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

            model.add(LSTM(500, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, name="sequence1", kernel_initializer=init))
            model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

            model.add(LSTM(500, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, name="sequence2", kernel_initializer=init))
            model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

            model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh', name='finale', kernel_initializer=last_init))

            model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.actor_lr))

            return model
```

Here is the code for the individual prediction:

```
 def policy(self, state):

        sampled_actions = tf.squeeze(self.actor_model(state))
        noise = self.ou_noise()
        # Adding noise to action
        sampled_actions = sampled_actions.numpy()

        transformed_action = ((3/2) * (sampled_actions + 1)) + noise

        if transformed_action > 0:
            return transformed_action[0]
        else:
            return 0
```

The shape of the incoming state is: (1, 10, 100)

The output of the model is:

```
tf.Tensor(
[1.        0.9999915 1.        1.        1.        1.        1.
 1.        1.        1.       ], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
```

Whereas I want it predicting just one timestep ahead, not 10.

I'm sure the answer is something simple, I've just been working on this all day and haven't cracked it. Thanks in advance!